# Difference on field based on other field value?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

So this is my model:

```
class InAndOut(models.Model):


   quantity = models.FloatField()
   date= models.DateField(null=True)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=12)
   id_product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to query distinct values based on id_product and for each one the difference quantity based on type field("in" or "out"):

So a real example would look like:

```
quantity = 1500
type = In
id_product = Gas

quantity = 300
type = Out
id_product = Gas

query - Gas 1200
```

Comment: Why not make the quantity negative if it is `out`?

Comment: Quantity can get negative,but how do I query this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**please use this code.**

```
qs =InAndOut.objects.filter(id_product='Gas')
diff_value=(qs.filter(types='In').annotate(Sum('quantity')).values()[0]['quantity__sum'] - qs.filter(types='Out').annotate(Sum('quantity')).values()[0]['quantity__sum'])
```

This code working for me.